# Secured data client side cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Are there any ways to cache secured data at client side **such that it cannot be modified by users** so that it is safe to be used again at server side ?

Or if there is any modification by user then it should be available but probably with flagged as not original data.

Comment: in short, no, client side operations can always be "hacked" one way or another.

Although you could try a ["Secure Cookie"](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies/) or a ["Signed Cooki"](http://code.google.com/p/django-signedcookies/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no.
Longer answer - you could probably use web storage/indexedDB/Web SQL Database, in conjunction with some kind of salted hash to check later that object hasn't changed, e.g.

1. Hash object with salt in server side
2. Send object and hash to user
3. get object and hash back from user
4. hash the object you got back from user again and check that the hash is equal to the one that you got back from user

Comment: No, salt should be kept in back-end and only hash should be sent to front-end.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any ways to cache secured data at client side such that it cannot be modified by users so that it is safe to be used again at server side?

**No.** Once the data is client-local, you've lost the game.

> Or if there is any modification by user then it should be available but probably with flagged as not original data.

You could sign this data with a key known only to the server. With cryptographic signing, anyone can verify the identity of the signer, but only someone with the private key can generate the "right" signature.

Answer (score 1):

Since storage on client side is limited to - `websql`(low support) `localStorage/sessionStorage`('argued support'), `indexedDB` (low support), and of course `cookies` are easily accessible, no, there is no way to secure data stored on the client side.Even if you encrypted the data using some JS method, the method could be found by a hacker.  Server side is the only true way to secure data using some sort of `HMAC`.